# including multiple example files for a same resource in RAML 0.8?

Tags: mule, raml

[enter image description here][1][I know my syntax is wrong in the image here . But just want to let you know what I'm trying to achieve.I'm using RAML 0.8. I want to include multiple requests and responses for a single resource. Can this be achieved in RAML 0.8? Your response is much appreciated. Thank you!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODWxV.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it conforms somewhat with [ask]. Specifically, you need to provide some sort of explanation of what you want to do, what you have tried and what results you got. Ideally you supply a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can have [multiple responses](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-08/raml-08.md#responses) in RAML 0.8, for example one for the 200 status code, one for the 404 status code, etc.
An example of this is:

```
/media/popular:
  displayName: Most Popular Media
  get:
    description: |
      Get a list of what media is most popular at the moment.
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            schema: !include instagram-v1-media-popular.schema.json
      503:
        description: |
          The service is currently unavailable or you exceeded the maximum requests
          per hour allowed to your application.
        body:
          application/json:
            schema: !include instagram-v1-meta-error.schema.json
```

You can specify several [requests](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-08/raml-08.md#body), but each for a different media type.
For example:

```
/jobs:
  post:
    description: Create a Job
    body:
      text/xml: !!null
      application/json: !!null
```

You **cannot** have multiple [examples](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-08/raml-08.md#example) in 0.8.
(In RAML 1 you can have multiple examples)